# How to remove the body unload event?

Tags: javascript

I have the following body unload event listener

```
  window.onbeforeunload = () => {
     return "Changes you made may not be saved.";
  };
```

How do I remove that particular one when I'm done with the background processing I have to do?

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload = null`

Comment: What if there are multiple before unloads on the page and I just want to cancel that one?

Comment: How can there be? You are only binding one handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove an event listener(like you mentioned incase of multiple eventlisteners),
you need to name your event handler function to an external function, not anonymous (so that you can reference that function):

**Update 1:**- I have added the message to be followed on screen

```js
   

 window.addEventListener("beforeunload", customFunction);

    function customFunction(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        return event.returnValue = "Are you sure you want to exit?";
    }
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload",customFunction);
```

Comment: If I want to show an alert to prevent the user to close the tab, what should I put in customFunction body?

Comment: I have updated my answer for the same